# Javascript write variable to div

Tags: javascript, html, variables, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I'm trying to write the variable "current" to the div "bank" using the following code when the user clicks on the image:
`document.getElementById('bank').innerHTML = current`

According to my research, this should work, but it doesn't. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css">
        <script>
            var current = 0;
            var totalThisGame = 0;

            function onButtonClick
            {
                current = current +1;
                totalThisGame = totalThisGame +1;
                document.getElementById('bank').innerHTML = current;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="left">
            <div id="bank">
            </div>
            <img id="image" src="img/image.png" alt="image" onclick=onButtonClick();>
        </div>
        <div id="middle">
        </div>
        <div id="right">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you miss the () behind your function

```
function onButtonClick()
            {
                current = current +1;
                totalThisGame = totalThisGame +1;
                document.getElementById('bank').innerHTML = current;
            }
```

your code is working fine for me

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to use them... how stupid.. :p It works fine now ;)

Comment: @MichaSprengers you should also accept this answer. This is how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I know and I will, I just had to wait for 10 minutes for some reason... So in a minute this will be accepted ;) Thanks for pointing it out tho

Answer (score 1):

**error**

```
change  function onButtonClick ->  function onButtonClick()

<img id="image" src="img/image.png" alt="image" onclick=onButtonClick();> to

<img id="image" src="img/image.png" alt="image" onclick="onButtonClick();">
```

Comment: Thanks that helped! But it doesn't matter if I use quotes around the onclick tho.. it works both ways..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<img id="image" src="img/image.png" alt="image" onclick="onButtonClick();">
```

Comment: If you could write that you wrote quotations, that would make us understand your proposal better :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is badly defined. It should be `function onButtonClick()` instead of `function onButtonClick`. Then use that HTML code : `<img id="image" src="img/image.png" alt="image" onclick="onButtonClick();">`

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the function parenthesis

```
       function onButtonClick()
        {
            current = current +1;
            totalThisGame = totalThisGame +1;
            document.getElementById('bank').innerHTML = current;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bank has to be in double quotes: 
document.getElementById("bank").innerHTML = current;

Answer (score 0):

Always use any of the functions on any event in html within double quotes.Try this

Answer (score 0):

You should read the console message and you'd notice that your function is odd.
Note parenthesis.

```
function onButtonClick
{
```

becomes

```
function onButtonClick()
{
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
function onButtonClick to  function onButtonClick()
```

`<img id="image" src="img/image.png" alt="image" onclick=onButtonClick();>`

to

```
<img id="image" src="img/image.png" alt="image" onclick="onButtonClick();">
```

it would be better if you put your javascript before the body closing tag or use window.onload method